# Event on Panel show in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i have a problem with an event on opening panel
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/panels/

when the panel is open I want show an allert message,
i try with the panel events but dont work any idea?

```
$("#filePanel").on("open",function(){
    alert("hi all");
});

$("#filePanel").on("close",function(){
        alert("byebye");
});
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct events are, `panelbeforeopen` and `panelbeforeclose`.

```
$("#filePanel").on("panelbeforeopen",function(){
 alert("hi all");
});

$("#filePanel").on("panelbeforeclose",function(){
    alert("byebye");
});
```

API: http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/#event-beforeclose

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#filePanel").on("panelopen",function(){
 alert("hi all");
});

$("#filePanel").on("panelclose",function(){
    alert("byebye");
});
```

API: http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/#event-beforeclose
Just modified @Omar's answer (dated 21 August 2013), to convey that `"panelopen"` and `"panelclose"` are also the events that can be used. ( I cant comment, so i had to put this as an answer)